# React Native WebView does not activate some Button/Link effects on Apple Podcasts

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native, react-native-webview

I am trying to play Apple podcasts through the desktop view of the Apple podcasts site using a React Native WebView component. For some reason none of the links or clickables within the `div.animation-wrapper.is-visible` do anything within the WebView. You can interact with them and they show the visual onClick effects, but nothing else happens.

I am using Android. This only occurs within the specified div, while the bottom bar and navbar still work. I tested the same pages on FireFox and Chrome desktop views where all effects still work. The problem can also be replicated on Android Studio Emulator (Pixel 5, API 34)

Code for the WebView:

```
    <WebView 
      source={{uri: uri }} 
      injectedJavaScript={`const meta = document.createElement('meta'); meta.setAttribute('content', 'width=820, initial-scale=0.5, maximum-scale=0.5, user-scalable=1'); meta.setAttribute('name', 'viewport'); document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(meta); `}
    userAgent="Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:109.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/115.0"
    javaScriptEnabled={true}
    domStorageEnabled={true}
    mediaPlaybackRequiresUserAction={false}
    />
```

This bug occurs on any podcast, here is an example:
https://podcasts.apple.com/us/podcast/search-engine/id1614253637